# Unable to edit an answer

Tags: support, bug, code-formatting

I am trying to edit an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/6049796), [this is current revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/11227902/19).

> Your post appears to contain code that is not 
>   properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using
>   the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more
>   editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

I am adding this text:

> - 32bit ARM code contains conditional bits in most instructions to make it possible to eliminate branching in short cycles at all. The innermost loop of C++ code will result in just two instructions for ARMv4 and later: one CMP instruction which updates the ALU result flags and one SUM instruction with according bit being set. [More about this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473e/BABCHFCB.html)

Or in raw markdown:

```
- 32bit ARM code contains conditional bits in most instructions to make it possible to eliminate branching in short cycles at all. The innermost loop of C++ code will result in just two instructions for ARMv4 and later: one CMP instruction which updates the ALU result flags and one SUM instruction with according bit being set. [More about this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0473e/BABCHFCB.html)
```

Copied post text just for reference:

Current: http://pastebin.com/yx51WARM

Proposed: http://pastebin.com/qLh5ihHC

How do I fix it?

Comment: Is the message unclear? What exactly are you trying to add to/remove from the answer?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I am not adding anything that looks like code.

Comment: Well could you save us from manually diffing two dumps of unformatted text and say what you *are* doing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: edited.

Comment: Diff in context: https://www.diffchecker.com/0c378lfd

Comment: The HTML generated from Markdown is cached. An edit triggers regenerating the HTML, and it's likely that this post contains code (well - or text) that triggers the error with the *latest* version of the MD renderer, where it did not do so on the last edit.

Comment: There are numerous backticks used in that post. Does this message mean that they should not be used?